# Electrical machines: electrical and mechanical properties of steels and cast iron

Tags: solid-state-physics, resource-recommendations, material-science, metals

I would like to know a good source of information for the common metals (steels and cast iron). Information that I need are basically the mass density and the electrical conductivity or resistivity. There are just too much source of information on the web and one doesn't know which source is accurate.

Comment: It is not so much about which source is accurate. There are several hundreds of different steel alloys that all have slightly different properties. The mass density can be calculated if you know the chemical composition to some degree, the electrical conductivity will depend on impurities, grain boundaries, ...

Comment: @ Alexander Thanks. Sure I agree with what you say but what about for some common metals and alloys. There should be some standard sources of information. 1 vote up.